# Style property of custom asp.net control throws exception when set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written custom control that inherits from System.Web.UI.Control. I have added Style property like this:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public CssStyleCollection Style
    {
        get { return ViewState["Style"] as CssStyleCollection; }
        set { ViewState["Style"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And I use it the following way

```
<custom:MyControl runat="server" Style="float: left; padding: 2px 4px;" ... />
```

When I attempt to load the page, I receive the following exception:

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection'
>   from its string representation 'float: left; padding: 2px 4px;' for the
>   'Style' property.

I suppose I should add a TypeConverter attribute to the property or something, but I could not find appropriate one in the System.Web.UI namespace. I also searched google and there was not much information for exactly this issue.
I know that this would have worked if I extended `WebControl` but I'd prefer a solution that deals with `Control`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're adding styles to an ASP.NET control, you should be able to use the standard `style` attribute. The attribute will likely be hidden from intellisense, but it's an accepted HTML attribute so it should still work:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;" />
```

Behind the scenes, the `style` attribute will be parsed and the properties will be loaded into the `Styles` collection:

```
string weight = TextBox1.Styles["font-weight"]; //== "bold"
```

Comment: Will I be able to access the styles programmatically form the Style property, rather than Attributes["style"]. I am looking for a clear way of working with the property in the code too. Maybe I'd better use WebControl as a base class, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Yes, the inline styles will be parsed and populated into the `Styles` collection behind the scenes.

Comment: OK, I'll wait a while and  probably accept your answer. Still I am curious to know if the exception can be avoided using a type converter or something.

Comment: You would probably have to create a wrapper for the `CssStylesCollection` that includes some logic to parse the markup and output the collection.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is what I am going to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved the problem but its not perfect:

1. Make the Style property of your custom control a string not a CssStyleCollection.

   Make a private instance variable of type CssStyleCollection.

   Use reflection to create an instance of CssStyleCollection using its private constructor.

   Set and Get the "Value" property of the private CssStyleCollection. This is a string and will be parsed when you set it.

   Override Render and use the "Value" property of the CssStyleCollection instance.

```
    private CssStyleCollection iStyle;
    public string Style 
    {
        get
        {
            if (iStyle == null)
            {
                iStyle = CreateStyle(ViewState);                    
            }
            return iStyle.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (iStyle == null)
            {
                iStyle = CreateStyle(ViewState);                    
            }
            //Could add differnet logic here
            iStyle.Value += value == null ? string.Empty : value;
        }
    }

    private static CssStyleCollection CreateStyle(StateBag aViewState)
    {
        var tType = typeof(CssStyleCollection);
        var tConstructors = tType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var tConstructor in tConstructors)
        {
            var tArgs = tConstructor.GetParameters();
            if (tArgs.Length == 1 && tArgs[0].ParameterType == typeof(StateBag))
            {
                return (CssStyleCollection)tConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { aViewState });
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter aOutput)
    {
        aOutput.AddAttribute("style", Style);

        aOutput.RenderBeginTag("span");
        foreach (Control tControl in this.Controls)
        {
            tControl.RenderControl(aOutput);
        }
        aOutput.RenderEndTag();            
    }
```

Comment: If I never use the Style property, I could get a `NullReferenceException` in the `Render` method, because iStyle will not be initialized. BTW, just out of curiosity, what do all the prefixes to the parameters and variables (like **a**Output in the `Render` method are supposed to mean? I've seen similar naming convention in old Visual C++ books, but this seems different.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Ivaylo Slavov. The null error should now be fixed by using Style instead of iStyle.Value. Regarding the prefixes i'm afraid all i know is they are part of a coding standard from a company I used to work for. "i" for instance variables, "a" for arguments and "t" for temporary / scoped variables.

Comment: Thanks, now the weird (IMHO) names make a little more sense to me. If you see the answer I already accepted, there is no need to manually instantiate the `CssStyleCollection`. The .NET will correctly populate the styles if I expose a string property, and having reflection calls in a web application is likely to become a bottleneck - just imagine the control in question being inside an `ItemTemplate` of a repeater, that is bound to a large data source. In the worst case, there will be as much reflection calls as many items are there. What I say is that your solution will work fine without it